# MySql Aurora - how often to run ANALYZE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, performance-tuning, aws-aurora

I have a database that has existed for about 10 years, with hundreds of tables, many of which have several million rows.

We don't have a DBA and we have an increasing number of slow queries. We're working to address those slow queries, but I'm curious about db tuning in general.

Do you think `ANALYZE TABLE` would get us any performance gains? Is this something that DBAs run regularly?

Comment: then you should thinking about increasing the hardware power, or removing some data into a backup and removing them from the database. of course you could try to optimize the queries

Comment: Let's see some of the slow queries.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of this query.

    SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM
information_schema.tables LIMIT 100000;   and we will get a check on data_free space used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rare for ANALYZE TABLE to make any significant improvement on query optimization.

You can run this command pretty freely. It's pretty low-impact. All it does is read a few pages of InnoDB tablespaces to sample the data, and it uses this to refresh statistics about row size, index distribution, etc. It reads a fixed number of pages, so it doesn't take long, regardless of the total size of the table.

The exact same operation happens automatically from time to time as you update rows in the table. It also happens automatically every time the instance is restarted, or if you rebuild indexes (many types of ALTER TABLE operations do this), or if you run OPTIMIZE TABLE.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-performance-optimizer-statistics.html for more details if you want to know.

Rarely, the index statistics get out of date after you change a lot of rows of data. In this case, you may improve the accuracy of query optimization by running ANALYZE TABLE. But only if the changes to data also significantly changed the data distribution.

Using ANALYZE TABLE is sort of a "hail mary" maneuver. Occasionally it makes a difference, and it's easy to do so you might as well try it. But don't get your hopes up.

What is much more likely to help your queries is to optimize them. This takes some time and understanding of how indexes help queries. Often a well-chosen index can help improve multiple queries, so it's a good bang for the buck.

I'm sorry to hear that you don't have a good DBA. You might consider hiring one, or at least contacting a consultant for a one-time review of your top slow queries.